# Can't compile 32bit with 64bit g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling

I'm using codeblocks. I'm using ubuntu. Here is output of compilation.

```
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Component.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Component.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Debug/ComData.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Debug/ComData.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Debug/DebugCom.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Debug/DebugCom.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Error/ErrorCom.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Error/ErrorCom.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Request.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Request.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/Site.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Site.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/WEBGINE/WEBGINE.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/WEBGINE.o
g++ -Wall  -O2  -m32 -nostdlib    -Iinclude  -c /home/miroslav/Development/WEBGINE/src/main.cpp -o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/main.o
g++  -o /home/miroslav/htdocs/freelife/index32.cgi obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Component.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Debug/ComData.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Debug/DebugCom.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Error/ErrorCom.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Request.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/Site.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/WEBGINE/WEBGINE.o obj/ReleaseCGI32/src/main.o   -s -m32 -L/usr/lib32/  
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

Little info about 32bit libs:

```
miroslav@miroslav-desktop:/usr/lib32$ ls -la libst*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 2010-06-21 20:50 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 975088 2010-03-27 01:16 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Be sure to install `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib`. These depend on both the 64 as the 32-bit gcc and stdc++ libraries.

Comment: thx. I had gcc-multilib, but i've not checked for g++-multilib :D

Comment: Check `gcc -v` in order to select the correct version, e.g. `gcc-4.4-multilib`

Comment: How in the world do you install these on a CentOS machine?

Comment: @ChristopherBales Did you installed yet ? Even I am struggling to install them on centOS

Comment: How about [`yum install glibc-devel.i386 libstdc++-devel.i386`](http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20080718/support-32-bit-development-libraries-64-bit-centos)?